# How to set up a ping task on Antergos/Arch Linux?

Tags: internet, ping, gateway

I want to set up a continuous task that pings a gateway every second. How would I go about it? The most performance friendly solution would be best.

No output needed, I just want it to ping.

Comment: What do you want the output of this task to be? Do you want it logged, or do you want notifications? What situation do you want to log/notify on (just ability to reach, or latency, or something else?) Do you really need 1-second resolution?

Comment: What do you want the task to do? Should it just keep pinging or should it react to packet drops etc?

Comment: @mattdm I don't want any output. I'm using a TP Powerline Adapter that keeps disconnecting. Apparently one of the easiest ways to fix it is to ping the gateway.

Comment: @sebasth Yes, I reckon it should just keep pinging, no records need to be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't too exact with your 1 second timeframe, you can use an infinite loop in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    ping -i 1 192.0.2.0
done
```

Should [`ping`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) exit, the loop starts it again. `-i` option sets the interval between pings.

Answer (score 1):

You can run ping forever(Until you restart your server) in the background using `nohup` :

```
nohup ping <Gateway address> &
```